# How can you change the icon of Quick Access in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer

I am personalizing the look of my Windows 10. So far I have been able to change almost every single icon to my custom style, but I seem to be unable to change the star icon of Quick Access to something else.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

I have tried using a DLL editor to edit imageres.dll, but the Quick Access icon does not seem to be in there.

Is it possible to change this icon through any means necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Change Quick Access Icon in File Explorer in Windows 10**

*This is a Registry tweak taken from [winaero.com](https://winaero.com/blog/change-quick-access-icon-in-file-explorer-in-windows-10/)*

1. Open Registry Editor.
2. Go to the following Registry key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID`
3. Right click on the CLSID in the key pane
   (the registry hierarchy, in the left pane) and select "New" → "Key".
4. Name it `{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}`. 
   This will be for a custom icon which will affect only your user account.
5. Right Click on `{679f85cb-0220-4080-b29b-5540cc05aab6}` in the key pane
   and select "New" → "Key".
6. Name it `DefaultIcon`.
7. Now select the `DefaultIcon` key (folder) and look to the value pane
   (the right pane) and, where says `(Default)   REG_SZ   (value not set)`,
   right click on the `(Default)` and set the string value to the full path of the icon file you want to set; e.g., `C:\Setting\Icons\QA.ico`,
   or you can use system icons by using strings like `imageres.dll,-1024`.
8. Once this is done, restart the Explorer shell or sign out and sign in again to your user account. If it doesn't help, refresh the icon cache.
9. Done.