# Remove the grey pins from Quick Access in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, icons, user-interface

*How to remove the grey pin icons from Quick Access in File Explorer in Windows 10?*

- So that they are transparent or turned off.
- Use of registry, hack or any means welcome, the simpler the better, prefer not to use a program if possible.
- Means of reverting.
- The only purpose is to decluter the user interface.
- Windows 10 Pro Version 1803

[image: How to remove the grey pin icons from Windows 10 Quick Access]

**Research:**

- The icon is located in: C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll
- Similar SU post [here](https://superuser.com/a/1189480/900431) for Quick Access icon change via registry
- Following on from that, searched through the registry for imageres.dll,-5100

  ```
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.PinToHome
  HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.PinToHome

  Explorer Handler {70438d09-456a-4a6f-86fe-1c1a3afc699e}
  Icon %SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-5100
  ```
- Have tried editing the icon location as Trusted Installer using [PowerRun_x64.exe](https://www.sordum.org/9416/powerrun-v1-3-run-with-highest-privileges/), to change it to a new transparent icon, such as with .reg file:

  ```
  Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

  [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\Windows.PinToHome]
  "Icon"="C:\\Settings\\Icons\\blank.ico"
  ```
- though no change occurred in file explorer.

---

*PowerRun is a portable freeware to launch regedit.exe , Cmd.exe or other software with the same privileges as the TrustedInstaller / Nt Authority/ System.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution provided by @Under A Tree seems to not work in Windows 10 Version 20H2. Here is an alternative solution.

1. Install ResourceHacker
2. Take control of your C:\Windows\SystemResources\imageres.dll.mun file. This can be done by opening CMD then inputting these commands

   cd C:\Windows\SystemResources

   takeown /f "%cd%" /r /d y

   icacls "%cd%" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)F /t /q
3. Make a copy of your C:\Windows\SystemResources\imageres.dll.mun file
4. create or download a transparent icon
5. open ResourceHacker and the C:\Windows\SystemResources\imageres.dll.mun file
6. click on Click on Icon Group
7. find 5100:1033
8. Select the icon and click control + r
9. Select the transparent icon
10. Use control + s to save

Answer (score 1):

Note: Apparently does not work anymore

*The current hack found [here](https://www.deviantart.com/mykou/art/Windows-10-Quick-access-grey-pinned-icons-hack-647555933) uses a free program called [CustomizerGod](https://www.door2windows.com/customizergod/).

 Program information at bottom of post.*

1. [Download](https://www.door2windows.com/download-freeware/#CustomizerGod) and Extract. Can check for viruses by uploading the exe to [virustotal.com](https://www.virustotal.com) *(Note:  [PsExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) in this program)*
2. Run CustomizerGod.exe as Administrator
3. Click on the General Icons Tab
4. Half way down the page there is two grey pins.
5. Select the one on the left ID#5100

[image: Select Grey Icon and Change]

7. Locate a blank icon. Create one (such as with [free portable IcoFX v1](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/icofx_portable)) or download [an icon here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/on7pp4hbuv12eql/blank.ico?dl=0) if you can't be bothered.
8. Now select the blank icon.
9. Done. Now it is changed.

[image: Grey Pin now blank]

---

**To Revert, reopen program:**

1. Run CustomizerGod.exe as Administrator
2. Click on the General Icons Tab
3. Select restore

[image: Select Restore]

If this does not work then the program can use [SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/929833/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system) to update it:

1. Click the three lines in the bottom right corner

[image: Three Lines]

2. Select Current File, Yes, Done (reboot to finish).

[image: Select File]

[image: Yes] [image: Prompt]

- Source: [How to Edit Grey Pinned Icons Windows 10 Hack](https://www.deviantart.com/mykou/art/Windows-10-Quick-access-grey-pinned-icons-hack-647555933)

---

**Programs:**

---

- CustomizerGod

*"CustomizerGod is the ultimate tool for customizing Windows. It lets you customize almost any part of Windows according to your taste. Like if you want the start button to look different, you can use CustomizerGod to change it from the Windows logo to something fun like a candy or a minion's face."* See website [here](https://www.door2windows.com/customizergod/).

---

- IcoFX Portable

IcoFX is an award winning freeware icon editor. It is an all-in-one solution for icon creation, extraction and editing. IcoFX has support for PNG compression icons for Windows Vista and later, MacOS iconx, conversion between Windows and Mac icons, icon libraries, website favicons, adding/changing/deleting icons in EXE files, alpha transparency, effects, 256x256 icons, true color + alpha, icon extraction from DLLs and EXEs, import and export of images, and more.
See IconFX Portable Apps page [here](https://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/icofx_portable).

Comment: I think that this will work, but it will undo pin icons for all of Windows, not only for Quick Access.

Comment: @harrymc Good point, what else is the pin icon used for?

Comment: Can't say, just pointing this out.