# Setting default icons for image files does not work? AKA: Changing the JPG icon?

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry, icons, regedit

I want to customise my JPG icons in Windows 10 (Home), and I should like to use the Windows registry to do so.

I have changed the *DefaultIcon* value under *HKCR\.jpg* to my custom icon, and the corresponding value under *HKCR\jpegfile* (which I have set as the ProgID for .jpg.)

The problem is that the changes do not show up on my desktop, even after refreshing the icon cache.

The user @UnderATree gave me a link, which proved useful, in that it referred me to *HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts*. I can see that *.jpg* has a *UserChoice* sub-key, and its *ProgID* value is set to *AppX43hnxtbyyps62jhe9sqpdzxn1790zetc*, which seems to be some Windows Picture programme.

Now, my problem is that one cannot easily undo user choices from the registry, and I do not know how to set the ProgID from the GUI (one can set the programme with which to open the files, but I want the ProgID to be *jpegfile*, which is not a programme in itself, I think.)

(I have edited this question as per the request of UnderATree. I hope I am making more sense now.)

EDIT: After having been diving into the issue, I have concluded that I simply wish to set the ProgID for  JPEG files. However, because of the *UserChoice* for JPEG's, I cannot do that. I can choose to open JPEG's with a particular programme through the GUI, but if I choose to open JPEG's with PaintBrush, for instance, they get the same icons as BMP's. I want the different file types to have different icons, even though I open them with the same programme. Does that make sense?

Comment: Maybe @Dominus you can rewrite your question to be more clear and specific. Things like [this](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/change-default-icon-file-type-windows/) or [this](https://superuser.com/a/1442993/900431) would be my suggestion if I am reading right, though backup the registry first :-). If I am correct you can write up an answer, or let me know and I will, just clarify your question first.

Comment: @UnderATree Thank you for your input. I hope that I have clarified my question.

Comment: So all you want is to change is the default jpg icon? Is that correct?

Comment: @UnderATree That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you wanted a registry solution, I would suggest using: File Types Manager from Nirsoft.

> FileTypesMan is an alternative to the 'File Types' tab in the 'Folder
>   Options' of Windows. It displays the list of all file extensions and
>   types registered on your computer. For each file type, the following
>   information is displayed: Type Name, Description, MIME Type, Perceived
>   Type, Flags, Browser Flags, and more.
>
> FileTypesMan also allows you to easily edit the properties and flags
>   of each file type, as well as it allows you to add, edit, and remove
>   actions in a file type.
>
> [Website](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) and [Download](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/filetypesman-x64.zip)

The great thing about it is you can review all the locations of the settings for things like image defaults and any extension.

If you simply right click, and edit selected file type you can also edit the default icon by selecting it.

[image: File Types Manager]

[image: Edit File Type]

This way you could change your registry in a more safe way, then manually look at and export your registry keys afterwards, to reverse engineer.

For changing icons there is a more complete tutorial [here](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/12383/change-a-file-types-icon-in-windows-7/).

Comment: That may be an even better solution. And I like your point about reverse engineering, since I really do want to know what is going on in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get a specific icon for JPEG's now, different from both BMP's and GIF's. I still have the Windows Photo programme, whose *DefaultIcon* is set to my JPG icon, open JPG's, but I chose to set GIF's to open with PaintBrush, which set its *ProgID* to be *PBrush*, not *Paint.Picture* as for BMP's.

Whilst I was hoping for a way to edit the *ProgID* directly, this solved my problem.

Thanks for the help, though!